# How to place subject scores under each subject in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these tables:

Table that displays the results after I fetched from db:
[image]

Result table from the database:
[image]

Subjects table from db:
[image]

What I am trying to achieve: I want the student identification number appear once and each subject score to appear under the subject just like the image below. How can I go about it in my SQL queries?

[image]

My source code:

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct s.regiNo, s.firstName as fname, s.middleName as mname, s.lastName as lname, s.gender, s.class_group, c.subjects, e.First_CA, e.Second_CA, e.examid, e.scored, e.internaltype, e.Class, e.Year FROM student s, subjects c, exam e WHERE s.regiNo = e.Roll_Number AND e.sub_id = c.subect_code
";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want *conditional* aggregation :

```
select s.regiNo as IdentityNumber, e.Class, s.class_group,
       sum(case when c.subect_code = 'math' then (e.First_CA + e.Second_CA + e.scored) else 0 end) as Mathematics,
       . . .
from student s inner join
     exam e
     on s.regiNo = e.Roll_Number inner join
     subjects c
     on e.sub_id = c.subect_code
group by s.regiNo, e.Class, s.class_group;
```